# Software for embedding massive earth data in website?

Tags: web-development, web, geo-location, geography

I am going to build a website either in Angular 5-6 or in something similar to Drupal.  I have experience building websites, but I am going to need to show massive amounts of data in a globe similar to google earth.

For example, this globe will need to show up to three million points where certain types of rocks have been found.  I have all of the data, I'm just not familiar with any newer technologies to visualize this data in a web page.

My requirements are that the technology be something fairly new/cutting edge, and be able to render hundreds of thousands, or possibly a few million data points on a map in a reasonable amount of time (feel free to use your own definition of reasonable).

Answer (score 2):

You could create one or sevaral "heatmap" layers from your processed data. This layer then gets shown when the user has a birds-eye view (focuses on, say, the entire earth), but the "heatmap" eventually gets replaced with specific markers for the point data only when the user zoomed in and has chosen a smaller region of interest.

You could also use "MarkerClusters"  for smaller patches of close-by points.

In sum there exist common GIS techniques for visualizing such type of data.
So maybe ask this on the gis.stackexchange website (do not cross-post the same question, modify it a bit), maybe try these tags: "webmapping", "simplify",  "smoothing", "kriging" ...

Comment: The heatmap when zoomed out, then individual points when zoomed in sounds exactly like what I want.  Thanks for the link to the gis stack exchange, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: There are many, many ways to interpolate such a layer from point-data, which best to use depends on user requirements and data characteristics. I don't think there is a single "best way".